# Impact of reducing numbers after decimal point on a 32-bits number Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What would be the impact of cutting to 2 numbers after the decimal point on a sane and logical 32-bits max number on both the performance, memory usage & the disk usage with an index containing millions of unique floating numbers ?

For instance: 1.34593495 becomes 1.35

Answer (score 0):

on millions? probably not a lot (at least, compared to the effort involved)

you'd likely see a reasonable impact when you reach billions. what that would be is hard to say, you'd probably want to test it out on your dataset and mappings

Comment: Thanks. "Not a lot" is very subjective. Is there a way to calculate the impact ?

Comment: it is, but fwiw it's based on a fair bit of experience with Elasticsearch. you test with your own data and https://github.com/elastic/rally